# Does Blender has input Degrees, Minutes and Seconds?

Tags: units

How can I enter angles in Degrees, Minutes and Seconds in Blender?
for example : 30º 23' 45 "

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly simple -- type the string `30d23'45''` into any valid rotation field. Note that Blender will take this input and convert it to the decimal form (`30.3958d`) if you click on the field again.